# Find Similar Records based on Title and Body Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

What's the best way to generate similar topics based on `title` and `body` attributes? (like Stackoverflow's related topics in the sidebar)

Generally, title is sufficient to generate similar records, but some records do not have a title. So the body is used (but it is far more text to search for)

Should I use `like` or `ilike` postgres queries (after filtering out stop words)? Or something like full text search.

Comment: The best approach is showing similar posts using `tags` or `category` then show which posts contain with this `tag` or `category` that will be similar, look at what might be help [Tagging](https://rubyplus.com/articles/4241-Tagging-from-Scratch-in-Rails-5) and [Rails Blog App With Category](https://medium.com/@bruno_boehm/full-blog-app-tutorial-on-rails-zero-to-deploy-4c19e8174791)

Comment: @fool-dev i'm looking specifically to only match by the `title` and `body` of the post. Similar to stackoverflow's right sidebar